# Append Nodes To Top of View Result

Tags: 7, views

I have a view with multiple taxonomy filters.  I need to have it set up so that when a certain term is chosen I need certain nodes to show up on top. Because of this I can't just simply use Sticky!

I'm thinking I will need to write something custom or perhaps use in addition to [EntityQueue](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityqueue).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a Flag and sorting by flag and using hook_views_query_alter() to remove the sort condidtion if the filters were not set in the views.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that a views attachment will inherit the exposed filters. You can add it from the same list where you find page, block etc.